# Transforming to WKTLine using JSTS library is very slow

Tags: openlayers-2, jsts

I have a performance issue with `JSTS` library. When my `OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString` has more than 1000 components (`OpenLayers.Geometry.Point`), transforming theses points with the `JSTS` library is very slow (often it kills the browser)

```
    function TransformLine(feature) {
        var line = feature;
        var OLParser = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
        var parsedLine = OLParser.write(line);
        var WKTReader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
        WKTLine = WKTReader.read(parsedLine);
        var WKTtoOLParser = new jsts.io.OpenLayersParser();
        WKTLine = WKTLine.buffer(20000, 2, 3)  // <== this line is very slow

        // ... drawing on map, skipped
}
```

Is there any way to boost perfomance of this operation?